# phpexcel looping through selected columns only

Tags: php, phpexcel

i have a huge sheet as my input , but i dnt have to read all columns i have to read selected columns only like B,H,I and J out of 36 columns and i will be very thank full if some code is also provided 4-5 lines .
at the momment i am using the following code !

```
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex('0') ;  
$i=0;$dum=false;$sum=0; 
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row)  
{
$cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();

$cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); 
if($dum)
{                                                  // iterated.
foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) 
{    if($i==1||$i==7||$i==8||$i==9)
    {
             if($i==1)
             {
             $value[$i]=$cell->getValue();
             $pieces = explode("_", $value[$i]);
          $asd=preg_split('#(?=\d)(?<=[a-z])#i',$pieces[0] );
            // $value[$i]=$asd[1];

             }
             if($i==7)
             {
             $value[$i]=PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($cell->getCalculatedValue(), 'Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
             $A=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value[$i]));
             $value[7]=$A;

             }
             if($i==8)
             {
             $value[$i]=PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($cell->getCalculatedValue(), 'Y-m-d H:i:s'); ;
             $num2=$value[$i];
             }
             if($i==9)
             { 
             $value[$i]=$cell->getValue(); 

             }
             echo $value[$i]; echo "|||||||";
                    }$i++; 

}$i=0; echo "<br>";
```

Answer (score 5):

This will be probably faster :

```
$highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow(); 
for ($row = 0; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
    // Fetch the data of the columns you need
    $col1 = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();
    $col7 = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $row)->getValue();
    $col8 = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(8, $row)->getValue();
    $col9 = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(9, $row)->getValue();

    /*
    ** INSERT HERE YOUR PHP CODE
    */

    echo $col1."||||||".$col7."||||||".$col8."||||||".$col9;
}
```